# Prevent foreach loop from repeating -laravel

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop

I fetch services from our database through code

```
'services' =>  Service::with('seller.user', 'seller.level', 'subcategory')
            ->whereHas('seller', function ($query) {
                return   $query->where('status', 'active');
            })
            ->Where('tags', 'like', '%' . $this->tag . '%')
            ->withAvg('review', 'rating')
            ->withCount('review')
            ->paginate(20)
```

How to ignore duplicate subcategories in the loop

```
 @foreach ($services as $service)
        $$service->subcategory->name
        @endforeach
```

I get a lot of duplicate subcategories

I need the details of the subcategory not just the name

relations

```
class Service extends Model
{
    public function subcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subcategory::class);
    }
}

class Subcategory extends Model
{
    public function service()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Service::class);
    }
}
```

table services

```
Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('seller_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('subcategory_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->string('slug')->nullable();
        $table->float('price')->nullable();
        $table->json('tags')->nullable();
    }
```

table subcategory

```
  Schema::create('subcategories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('name');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way:

```
@php
$subcategories = array();
foreach ($services as $key => $service) {
    array_push($subcategories, $service->subcategory->name);
}
$subcategories = array_unique($subcategories);
@endphp
@foreach ($subcategories as $key => $subcategory)
    {{ $subcategory }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need the details of the subcategory, not just the name

Comment: So where is the data you don't want to repeat?

Answer (score 0):

Get only unique ids or unique name. May differ with your db.

```
'services' =>  Service::with('seller.user', 'seller.level',
 'subcategory' => function($query) {
          $query->get()->unique('name')
      })
       ->whereHas('seller', function ($query) {
            return   $query->where('status', 'active');
        })
        ->Where('tags', 'like', '%' . $this->tag . '%')
        ->withAvg('review', 'rating')
        ->withCount('review')
        ->paginate(20);
```

Also can use below methods

1. `->distinct('name')->get();`
2. `->distinct()->get(['name']);`

For more check [Aggregating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models)

Comment: Thank you. I tried all the codes, but the result of duplicate subcategories

Comment: could you please update the question with db table structure and relations